# MySQL skip a column name when inserting values

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which the first column is auto_increment. I want to insert data into the table, but skip the first column as it is updated automatically when a new row is begun.
so:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL,"lady","gaga","rulz");
```

But NULL cannot be inserted into a column as I specified earlier. **What do I need to replace NULL with so that the column doesn't get anything inserted into it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure you specify the respective column names

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ("lady","gaga","rulz");
```

You don't even need to fill all columns (if they are not required), Ie.

```
INSERT INTO table (col2) VALUES ("gaga");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into table(field1, field2, field3) values('lady', 'gaga', 'sucks')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although 'sucks' would cause a malfunction since it is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @Galen, LOL, at least she didn't -Rep you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly specify the column names and order. In other words

```
INSERT INTO table (field2, field3, field4) VALUES ("lady","gaga","rulz");
```

BTW it is typically a good idea to avoid the implicit insert syntax (but maybe for the simplest / debug time snippets), lest you get surprised when/if the underlying table schema was somehow changed.

Also, so you know, ***something*, will get inserted into the (here) field1 column**.  When you define or alter the schema of a table, a given field can either be nullable or not, and/or it can have a default value or not.  In the SQL provided above, you can only omit the values for fields that are either nullable or have a default value; SQL will otherwise return an error and won't insert any part of the new record.